# Is it really necessary to have three tags for Plants vs Zombies?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Currently, there are three tags for Plants vs Zombies: [plants-vs-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plants-vs-zombies), [plants-vs-zombies-goty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plants-vs-zombies-goty) and [plants-vs-zombies-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plants-vs-zombies-series) . Do we really need 3 tags for one game? Specially considering the low number of questions in the "goty" and "series" tags.

Comment: agreed, merged them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: Nope!

Slightly longer answer: The differences between the two versions of the game are minor at best. I can't think of anything that would require a tag to differentiate between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Are there important differences from the normal game and the GotY version such that it warrants value to separate the questions about them? Not just as far as existing questions, but what might show up. Consider the differences between just a patches and touch-ups (AoSX on PC versus PSN release, for example), a full expansion pack (Diablo II, Armored Core, etc.), and a sequel. If you're approaching expansion pack level of difference or beyond, then the second tag seems appropriate.

Are the two games then separate enough to warrant a series tag? If the GotY version is distinctly different to represent the *sequel* level of difference, then a series tag is useful. But if it represents an expansion pack or lower, then it basically inherits its features primarily from the original game.

Comment: [The GotY edition added](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Game_of_the_Year_PC_Version) achievements, an avatar creator, and changed the graphics on one of the zombies from a Michael Jackson-esque dancer to a more generic "Disco Stu" version.

Comment: @Brant Sounds like it's shy of being Expansion Pack level, then. Good thing I pre-emptitively upvoted your answer!